# Appending a XML fragment in Another xml in Python

Tags: python, xml

Need to read a CSV file and using the details in it need to create an XML snippet, That needs to be placed in another snippet of XML in a particular area(Inside a node).
The first portion is completed. Need to do the second portion. need some help in this area. Also the result needs to write in the new XML file.

```html
import csv
import lxml.etree as ET
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ETT
from lxml import etree, html

csvFile = open('parameters.csv')
readCsv = csv.reader(csvFile)
data = []

for row in readCsv:
    data.append(row)
csvFile.close()

def convert_row(row):
    return """<hashTree><TransactionController guiclass="TransactionControllerGui" testclass="TransactionController" testname="%s" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="TransactionController.includeTimers">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="TransactionController.parent">false</boolProp>
        </TransactionController>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="HTTP Request" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments" />
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">"%s"
            </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">
            </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">
            </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding">
            </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">"%s"
            </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">"%s"</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re">
            </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout">
            </stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout">
            </stringProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        </hashTree>
        </hashTree>"""%(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])

fragment = '\n'.join([convert_row(row) for row in data[1:]])

TF = ET.parse('testXml.xml')
content = TF.findall("//jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/")
content.append(fragment)

print(content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert string to XML before appending.

```
fragment = '\n'.join([convert_row(row) for row in data[1:]])
aet=ET.fromstring(fragment)
TF = ET.ElementTree(file='testXml.xml')
for child in TF.xpath('//jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree[1]'):
child.append(aet)
TF.write('out.jmx')
```